# Putting Project Documentation on Sharepoint via <summary> tags

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, documentation, sharepoint-2010, comments

I was wondering if there was a way to stick documentation generated by XML Comments onto a Sharepoint server?

I have been looking around and I haven't been able to find a method to put the XML files that VS creates onto a Sharepoint server.  I have looked at Sandcastle and that doesn't quite do what I want.  Anyone got any ideas?  Would I need to develop a Sharepoint extension for this or what?

Answer (score 0):

with powershell you can easily read a file xml her is an exemple:

$xml = [xml] ( get-content ip.xml )

$site = Get-SPSite $xml.sites.site.ip

xml file ip.xml:

`<sites>
    <site>
        <ip>URL</ip>
    </site>
</sites>`